# How to get the path of a file without normalisation in ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb, working-directory

My current directory path is `/a/b/c/`
When I do

```
fname = File.path("../test.rb")
::File.absolute_path(fname)
```

output is: `/a/b/test.rb`

What I am expecting is the output something like this: `/a/b/c/../test.rb`

Basically I need the path of a file without normalisation of `../` and `~`

Comment: `current_dir = Dir.pwd
puts current_dir
`or
`file_path = File.expand_path('example.rb')
puts file_path`

Comment: try 
`base_dir = "/a/b/c/";
fname = "../test.rb";
absolute_path = File.expand_path(fname, base_dir);

puts absolute_path  # Output: "/a/b/c/../test.rb";`

Comment: @Gupta that's not the output of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could build it yourself via [`File.join`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/File.html#method-c-join):

```
Dir.pwd
#=> "/a/b/c"

File.join(Dir.pwd, "../test.rb")
#=> "/a/b/c/../test.rb"
```

Note that [`Dir.pwd`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Dir.html#method-c-pwd) returns the current working directory. To get the current file's directory, use [`__dir__`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try File.realpath() methods. For example:

```
fname = File.realpath("test.rb", __dir__)
```

This will give you the absolute path with '..' references intact.

Comment: No, This doesn't help. realpath also normalises `../` references

Comment: Also, `__dir__` is the directory of the file in question, which is not necessarily the same as the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: not what OP wants, see comment by Stefan.

You want to `expand_path`

```
3.0.6 :003 > Dir.pwd
 => "/something/somewhere"
3.0.6 :004 > File.expand_path("../foo")
 => "/something/foo"
3.0.6 :005 >
```

Comment: The OP wants to retain `..`, i.e. `/something/somewhere/../foo`

Comment: thanks... i conveniently skipped over "normalisation" in "without normalisation" :-)